# Reading data into R

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics, large-data, r-environment

I am trying to read data from the msigdb database into my R environment, but I am having trouble reading it into the format that I would like. Right now when I read the data in it is read as the type "integer", I want it read in as the type "character" or any other type so that when I transfer data between data frames/matrices I dont get the integer value for the item instead of the written letters that comprise the name of the item.

```
df<-read.table("msigdb.v5.2.symbols.txt", fill = TRUE)
```

This is what I currently have, but like I said when I do `typeof(df[1,1])` I get `"integer"`.

To summarize:
After reading in data with columns that should be character, the current behavior is: `typeof(df[1,1)]` produces `"integer"`. The desired behavior is: `typeof(df[1,1]]` produces `"character"`

Reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)
write.table(band_instruments, "test.txt")
df <- read.table("test.txt", header = TRUE)
typeof(df[1,1])
# [1] "integer"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
df<-read.table("msigdb.v5.2.symbols.txt", fill = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

By default, `read.table` reads all columns as `character` unless specified otherwise in `colClasses`*, and `read.table` and `data.frame` convert characters to factors. When you extract a single cell of a factor, it's going to show as the internal integer code.

Setting `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the call to `read.table` resolves this.

*despite the comment below, this is true. `read.table` reads all columns as character first, then converts them. This is in the documentation, and you can see it from the source code. You can confirm this with the following code:

```
write.table(mtcars, "mtcars.txt")
read.table("mtcars.txt", header = TRUE, quote = ".")
# Fails because it reads the decimals in the numeric data as quotes
# From the documentation: Quoting is only considered for columns read
# as character, which is all of them unless colClasses is specified
```

Comment: That's directly from the documentation. It reads them as character first, then converts them. See even my answer, where I describe how in this particular case they become factors

Comment: The previous commenter deleted their comment, but I'll leave up my response anyway, for others who don't know about this behavior.